# EF Core Store navigation properties in same table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity that looks like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public UserAddress Address {get;set;}
}

public class UserAddress
{
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public string ZipCode {get;set;}
}
```

In code it makes sense to have the `Address` as a sub class inside the `User` class. But in my database I want to have the `Address` property mapped in the same table as where the `User` data is stored.

So I want something like this in the database when I save the entity:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Id | UserName | Address_Street | Address_ZipCode |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | John Doe | Street 100     | 12345           |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I tried it by using `builder.HasOne(x => x.Address)`, but that doesn't work.

How can I tell EF Core to save both objects to the same table?

Comment: [Learn your ORM(owned entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv a basic question is still a valid question.  This should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().OwnsOne(o => o.UserAddress);
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities